# PMD : DD anomaly for variable

Tags: java, pmd

I am using Eclipse with the PMD Plug-in (4.0.0.v20130510-1000) and got a lots of those violations and solved most of them, but i don't understand why **`DD anomaly`** occurs into below code

```
private boolean createFile(final String szFileName){
    final File oFile = FileUtils.getFile(szFileName);
    boolean bStatus;
    try {
        FileUtils.touch(oFile);
        bStatus = true; // DD anomaly
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        log.error("Failed to create new file. "+ e);
        bStatus = false;
    }
    return bStatus;
}
```

I can't use multiple return statements, because `multiple exit point` rule gets break.

Tried another way, but getting DD anomaly to another line,

```
private boolean createFile(final String szFileName){
        final File oFile = FileUtils.getFile(szFileName);
        boolean bStatus = true; // DD anomaly
        try {
            FileUtils.touch(oFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            log.error("Failed to create new file. "+ e);
            bStatus = false;
        }
        return bStatus;
    }
```

Comment: Why not initially set `bStatus` to `true` and, if an exception is thrown, set it to false? No need to set it to `true` in the `try` block.

Comment: @JonnyHenly tried this one but now `boolean bStatus = true;` getting DD anomaly.

Comment: Why not have `createFile` throw an `IOException` and handle it upstream? Then you could have `createFile` return `void`, or better yet have it return the file it created.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes, this is perfect. Thanks !

Comment: I'll add it as an answer in case anyone else has a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to have `createFile` throw an `IOException` and handle it upstream. Then you could have `createFile` return `void`, or better yet have it return the file it created. That will get rid of the `DD anomaly` you are receiving.

**Alternative `createFile`:**

```
private File createFile(final String szFileName) throws IOException {
    final File oFile = FileUtils.getFile(szFileName);        
    FileUtils.touch(oFile);

    return oFile;
}
```